Why is the electric field non-zero inside a conducting sphere with a charge placed in the center?

In the last paragraph, if I evaluate ${U_1}$ using $E = k_e \frac{q}{r^2}$, yes I agree this can be infinity due to the lower bound of the integral being 0. But wouldn't $E$ be $0$ since it's inside a conductor?
I am a little confused. Thanks for the answers.

Using Gauss Law the field in regions external to the  conductor is not zero.  Fields inside the shell made up of the conductor is zero.

Did you miss that it's a spherical shell, not a solid sphere? Inside the sphere is not "inside a conductor" in the sense that there must be zero electric field. That's only within the conducting material. Regions that are not within conducting material but surrounded by a conductor are not required to have zero electric field.

@AXensen Thank you for your comment, I did not realize this difference. Thanks.

But wouldn't E be 0 since it's inside a conductor?
The problem relates to a spherical conducting shell which is assumed to be of negligible thickness.
The work done is used to create the additional electric field produced in the volume which was outside the initial position of the spherical shell.
This is because the electric field inside the volume defined by the original size of the shell is unchanged.
Thus one can avoid any problems with infinities as the distance from the charge tends to zero by just computing the energy stored in the electric field from the initial radius of the shell, $a$, to infinity, the volume in which the additional field was created.
